# How can I set a methods return type as the same as the class its currently in

Tags: c#, class, networking

Intermediate C# programmer here. I'm writing a networking wrapper, and want each type of packet to be able to define its own 'OpenPacket' method which will take in a parameter of a class of the same type as the current class. I also want another method 'WriteToPacket' which will return a packet of the same type as its current class.

Eg. A MessagePacket class's WriteToPacket will return a MessagePacket. I would use inheritance and just return a Packet type, but each packet has different variables. Also, I'm developing it as a library, so I would like new packet types to be able to be defined outside of the dll.

I have a interface for the packet type

```
public interface IPacket_Type<T> where T : class
{
    T OpenPacketFromMessage(NetIncomingMessage msg) ;
    NetOutgoingMessage PackPacketIntoMessage(NetOutgoingMessage msg, T packet);
}
```

I use this as part of a packet

```
public class TestPacket : Packet, IPacket_Type<TestPacket> {
    public int testInt;

    public TestPacket(string packet_name) : base(packet_name){}

    public TestPacket OpenPacketFromMessage(NetIncomingMessage msg)
    {
        TestPacket packet = new TestPacket(packet_name);
        packet.testInt = msg.ReadInt32();

        return packet;
    }

    public NetOutgoingMessage PackPacketIntoMessage(NetOutgoingMessage msg, TestPacket packet)
    {
        msg.Write(packet_name);
        msg.Write(packet.testInt);
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Upon receiving the class name on the serverside i would like to be able to instantiate a class like that. Eg, make a TestPacket instance rather than one of a packet. A way i thought about doing this, would be to make a packet class which returns its current type, therefore allowing me to use it as a base, always returning the type of the class.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What if you made the packet base class type Generic to accept an implementation just like with the interface?

Answer (score 1):

In the following code I'm showing you some examples of how to work with instances of the same class:

```cs
public class Sample {
    // This method returns the same instance of the sample class
    public Sample ReturnSampleInstance() {
        return this;
    }

    // This method creates a completely new instance of the class with other data
    public Sample ReturnAnotherSampleInstance() {
        var sample = new Sample();
        // Perform some logic with the new sample instance or fill up some data
        return sample;
    }

    // This method receives an instance of the same class and returns it
    public Sample ReceivesSampleInstanceAndReturnIt(Sample sampleInstance) {
        return sampleInstance;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to use an interface and that the method of the interface to have a return type as the implementation class you could do it as follows:

```cs
// Generic Interface 
public interface ISample<Timplementation> {
    Timplementation GetCurrentInstanceUsingAnInterface();
}

// Class that implements the interface and passes itself to the ISample interface as a generic parameter
public class Sample : ISample<Sample> {
    // This method returns the same instance of the sample class
    public Sample ReturnSampleInstance() {
        return this;
    }

    // This method creates a completely new instance of the class with other data
    public Sample ReturnAnotherSampleInstance() {
        var sample = new Sample();
        // Perform some logic with the new sample instance or fill up some data
        return sample;
    }

    // This method receives an instance of the same class and returns it
    public Sample ReceivesSampleInstanceAndReturnIt(Sample sampleInstance) {
        return sampleInstance;
    }

    // Get the current instance of the class through the method of the interface
    public Sample GetCurrentInstanceUsingAnInterface() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the response! Yeah, I initially thought about doing this, but at the moment each packet uses an interface where the return method needs to be described. I have used a generic, however later on I need to retrieve the class type

Comment: The same thing can be done using generic types. Could you provide a bit more context? maybe some code so I could help you with that

Comment: I think I already understood what you want. If you want your interface to return an instance of the actual implementation you could do it by using a generic parameter TImplementation, I've edited the code to show you how

Comment: I've updated the post with more specific information. Could you take a look?